# Can an adjective modify an adjective in "low-resistant infectious agents"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives

I was translating a Russian sentence and came up with "low-resistant infectious agents":

> Infectious agents in animals (including birds) can be divided into four groups based on their resistance to chemical disinfectants: **low-resistant**, resistant, highly resistant and super resistant.

I googled for "low-resistant" and there are examples, although those seem to have been penned by non-native speakers of English. Would "low-resistant infectious agents" be acceptable with the hyphen, or should I instead use some other word?  I thought of  "slightly" but "slightly resistant infectious agents" looks a bit odd.. "weakly resistant infectious agents"?

I'm unsure which word to pick if not "low-resistant". If if modify it to "low-**resistance**", then it would fall out of tune with the other three terms in the range.

Comment: Just as a side note, a decent way to get a quick handle on English terminology in this realm is to append `site: nih.gov` to a google query, for example `microbial resistance site: nih.gov`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think "low" is a good choice. I would use "somewhat" or "moderately" resistant instead:

> Based on their review, the researchers estimate that between 39 percent and 51 percent of surgical site infections and 27 percent of post-chemotherapy infections are caused by bacteria already **somewhat resistant** to antibiotics.
>   <sup>[Antibiotic Resistance May Threaten These Patients](https://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/news/20151015/antibiotic-resistance-could-threaten-surgery-chemo-patients#2)</sup>

or this of "moderately resistant" and "highly resistant" in [Kucers' The Use of Antibiotics Sixth Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=xlQ1hqp9ngwC&pg=PA621&dq=%22high%20resistance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib3se9x6rZAhVs3IMKHXHiB8AQ6AEISTAH)

I don't think "resistance" is a good substitute for "resistant". 
If you compare results from Google Books between "[high resistance](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22high%20resistance%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)" and "[highly resistant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22highly%20resistant%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)", "high resistance" returns results that even when they are in a medical context are describing something other than an infectious agent, for example,

> using antibiotics with a "low resistance potential" in place of those with a "high resistance potential," ([*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xlQ1hqp9ngwC&pg=PA621&dq=%22high%20resistance%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwib3se9x6rZAhVs3IMKHXHiB8AQ6AEISTAH))

> In addition, the PSV Figure 9.1 High resistance flow proximal to severe occlusive disease. (A) Common carotid Doppler has a high resistance, triphasic waveform secondary to ICA occlusion. ([*](http://%20In%20addition,%20the%20PSV%20Figure%209.1%20High%20resistance%20flow%20proximal%20to%20severe%20occlusive%20disease.%20(A)%20Common%20carotid%20Doppler%20has%20a%20high%20resistance,%20triphasic%20waveform%20secondary%20to%20ICA%20occlusion.))

and "highly resistant" favors results related to infection or infestation. Using "resistance" instead of "resistant" doesn't make much of a grammatical difference, but it does seem to run contrary to what is commonly used in other similar contexts.

Answer (score 1):

No, "low-resistant" should be "minimally resistant". But you could also label your categories with nouns:  low resistance, normal resistance, high resistance, and almost complete resistance.